# On launching 3d sensor: no device connected

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reading through the [tutorial](http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/8/) I came to *turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch*

I receive  *No devices connected... waiting for devices to be connected*.
However, Kinect worked with previous *openni_launch openni.launch*
(in order to make it work, I had to change Globaldefaults.ini, as suggested in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/61211/problem-with-xtion-pro-live-and-openni_camera/?answer=61212#post-id-61212), if this info helps )

Did anybody have the same problem? What could be possible fixes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227917/on-launching-3d-sensor:-no-device-connected/) by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 526 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I actually didn't have Kinect, but Asus Xtion Pro. However, as previously Kinect was used, the environment variable ROS_3D_SENSOR (in my ~/.bashrc file) was set to Kinect.
It was enough to remove ROS_3D_SENSOR=kinect from ~/.bashrc file (as asus xtion pro is default for indigo, according to [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot/indigo/Migration))

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-03-04**:
I consider this question answered, but can't yet accept the answer as I don't have enough points

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-03-04**:
I voted up your answer. You should have enough karma to accept your own answer now.